# How create a view similar to image?

Tags: iphone

I am new iPhone dev and I want to create a screen like below image.

[image]

How to do that?

Comment: What have you tried already? What is it you don't understand about creating a view like this?

Comment: You start by reading the Apple documentation on iOS development and learn how to create a simple single view app. Then progress from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just look at the code for that then? i.e. here - https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBDialog.m

Comment: +1 ha ha ha...absolutely right mattjgalloway

Answer (score 0):

You can create subView to do like that and set size as well. Make the Previous view interaction disable when subview over the view.